# Customize/Remove these sections in "shopping cart" page woocommerce?

Tags: css, wordpress, woocommerce, shopping-cart

How do I remove [these sections](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4NAVH.png) on woocommerce "shopping cart" page? Preferably with CSS (I'm using Site Origin CSS plugin to edit my CSS).

I found CSS code to remove "has been added to your cart" text but it did not work...

```
.woocommerce-checkout .woocommerce .woocommerce-message {
display:none !important;}
```

And while we are at it, how do I replace quantity and add to cart button with custom button (my image) for it [to look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qPJRV.png)? This is [how it looks now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZTWwu.png).

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Unless `.woocommerce` and `.woocommerce-message` are children of `.woocommerce-checkout`, this will not work. If these are classes styling separate elements, put a comma between them, like `.woocommerce-checkout, .woocommerce, .woocommerce-message{...}`

Also, make sure that these are the classes you really want to disable. Often times in WP sites, there are 10+ classes on a single element and it can be difficult to make sure you're targeting the right one. `.woocommerce`, for example, seems like a generic class, so hiding it could break other things throughout the site.